# MySQL / PHP - Time Question

Tags: php, mysql, time

In my DB I stored the time of the last page refresh in a TIME column. I want to compare the last page refresh to the current time now and find out how many 5 minuet periods have passed?

I was thinking take the last page refresh and subtract it from the current time then divide by 5. But I don't know about how things are formatted.

Help me please!

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using `DATETIME` instead of just `TIME`?

Comment: I don't need to know the date.

Comment: @shorty Of course you do. How else are you going to be able to tell if the time there is from today, yesterday or 1 year ago?

Comment: well if the current time is less than the last refresh i will assume a day has passed

Comment: Why assume a day has passed? What if actually 2 days passed? You are adding assumptions and complicating something that should've been simple (eg: just use a full date or a unix timestamp)

Comment: well if you can modify cichys query to include a date and tell when its been over 75 minuets. I will use yours.

Comment: yeah i thought about it and i think your right..but I dont know how..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *, FLOOR(((UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-time_field)/300)) AS periods FROM table
```

Im not sure for if UNIX_TIMESTAMP() returns correct timestamp, you will have to check it ;)
EDIT: checked it myself and its working great ;)

Comment: im assuming unix_timestamp is the current time and time field is the last page refresh? sorry kinda new to php >.<

Comment: Yes, in this query you should only change name of the table, and "time_field" to name of the column you have your last refresh, and it should work right away.

Comment: ok ill try it! thanks. but where does it tell me how many 5 min periods have passed?

Comment: I added name of the field where you will have 5 min periods counted, if you want to change it to 10 min etc, just change 300 to (60 * x) where x is minutes.